# Simple fadeIn always lagging

Tags: performance, animation, html, render

I'm having issues with all the animations on the page lagging when I choose to display this picture. I have tried displaying it with fadeIn, visibility, animate:opacity, display:block, and no matter which way I reveal it still causes the browser to choke. There has to be a way around this. (I've also tried preloading the image and it makes no difference!)
Is it just the size of the image?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZJpmT/2/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is the image size. Doing a quick test showed that a fadeIn with a duration of 5 seconds, could be shown, but using a duration of 1 second wouldn't show any fade effect at all, but just show the the image at once.

Animating an image which is 1MB in size isn't what you want to do. If you really need this image to be that large, try to add a background to each frame, which matches the pages background and save it as JPG. That could reduce the size a bit, but it's not guaranteed that it will stop the browser from choking.